# C++ - Reading Columns of a CSV files and only keeping ones that start with a specific string

Tags: c++, csv

so I am trying to figure out how to sort CSV files to help organize data that I need for an economics paper. The files are massive and there are a lot of them (about 587 mb of zipper files). The files are organized by columns in that all the variable names are in the first line and all the data for that variable is all below it. My goal is to be able to only take the columns that start with the an indicated string (ex input: "MC1", Get: MC10RT2,MC1WE02,...) and then save them into a separate file. Does anyone have any advice as to what the form that the code should take?

Comment: Use a spreadsheet.  They are very good at this sort of thing.  Some even have a scripting language.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to go through all the different files I need? The problem is that I have to sort a total of 145 excel files in CSV format. Could I use the scripting between documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun a small program that should work for you. The thing you'll be intersted in is `boost::split(columns, str, boost::is_any_of(","), boost::token_compress_off);` that here create a `vector` of `string` from your csv-style string.

Very basic example, but your question was an excuse to play a bit with boost string algorithms, that I did know but never used...

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// Typedefs for eye candy
typedef std::vector<std::string> Fields;
typedef std::vector<Fields> Results;
typedef std::set<unsigned long> Columns;


// Split the CSV string to a vector of string
Fields split_to_fields(const std::string& str)
{
  Fields columns;

  boost::split(columns, str, boost::is_any_of(","), 
    boost::token_compress_off);
  return columns;
}

// Read all the wanted columns
Results read_columns_of_csv(std::istream& stream, const Columns& wanted_columns)
{
  std::string str;  
  Results results;

  while (getline(stream, str))
  {
    Fields line{split_to_fields(str)};
    Fields fields;

    for (unsigned long wanted_column: wanted_columns)
    {
      if (line.size() < wanted_column)
      {
        std::cerr << "Line " << (results.size()  + 1 )
          << " does not contain enough fields: "
          << line.size() << " < " << wanted_column
          << std::endl;         
      }
      else
      {       
        fields.push_back(line[wanted_column]);
      }
    }

    results.push_back(fields);
  }

  return results;
}

// Read the ids of the columns you want to get
Columns read_wanted_columns(unsigned long max_id)
{
  Columns wanted_columns;
  unsigned long column;
  do
  {   
    std::cin >> column;

    if ((column < max_id)
        && (column > 0))
    {
      wanted_columns.insert(column - 1);
    }
  }
  while (column > 0);

  return wanted_columns;
}

// Whole read process (header + columns)
Results read_csv(std::istream& stream)
{
  std::string str;

  if (!getline(stream, str))
  {
    std::cerr << "Empty file !" << std::endl;
    return Results{};
  }

  // Get the column name
  Fields columns{split_to_fields(str)};

  // Output the column with id
  unsigned long column_id = 1;
  std::cout 
    << "Select one of the column by entering its id (enter 0 to end): " 
    << std::endl;
  for (const std::string elem: columns)
  {
    std::cout << column_id++ << ": " << elem << std::endl;
  };

    // Read the choosen cols
  return read_columns_of_csv(stream, read_wanted_columns(column_id));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Manage errors for filename
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Please specify a filename" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);

    if (!file)
    {
         std::cerr << "Invalid filename: " << argv[1] << std::endl;   
         return -2;
    }

    // Process 
    Results results{read_csv(file)};

    // Output
    unsigned long line = 1;

    std::cout << "Results: " << results.size() << " lines" << std::endl;
    for (Fields fields: results)
    {
      std::cout << line++ << ": ";
      std::copy(fields.begin(), fields.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ","));
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This helps tremendously, thank you so much... I want to upvote you so badly but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Please know that you have my gratitude. If my thesis paper actually gets published I will come back to site to include you as help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a vector of structures.

The structure will allow each row to have a different type.

Your program would take on the following structure:

1. Read data into a the vector.
2. Extra necessary fields out of each structure in the vector and write
   to new file.
3. Close all files.

Comment: Ok, as of right now my program is bare bones but I was thinking of a vector<vector<string>> to input all of it, I am assuming that whenever the program finds the column it wants it should just do a row++, is is there anything I should keep in mind with this kind of structure?

Comment: If you don't need to compare integers or doubles, then treating each field (column) as a string will work.